# "file" command yields "ASCII text, with no line terminators", unless I first edit the file in vim

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, python, ascii

I am experimenting a strange behaviour which I don't know how to solve. I will explain the scenario:

- From a Python script I'm getting a json from a simple application
  hosted on [parse](https://parse.com/).
- Once I get the text, I get a sentence from it
  and save it to a local "txt" file saving it as iso-8859-15.
- Finally I send it to a text to
  speech processor, which expects receiving it on ISO-8859-15

The weird thing is that once the python script runs, if I run

```
file my_file.txt
```

The output is:

```
my_file.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

But if I open `my_file.txt` with vim, then remove the last "dot" of the sentence,  write it again, and save the file: if I do again:

```
file my_file.txt
```

now the output is:

```
my_file.txt: ASCII text
```

Which solves some problems when processing the voice synthesizer. So, how can I force this behaviour automatically without doing the vim stuff? I have also done many tries with `iconv` with no success.

Any help would be much appreciated

**Edit:**

```
i@raspberrypi ~/main $ hexdump -C my_file.txt

00000000  73 61 6d 70 6c 65 20 61  6e 73 77 65 72 2e 2e     |sample answer..|
0000000f

pi@raspberrypi ~/main $ file my_file.txt
my_file.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators
pi@raspberrypi ~/main $ vim my_file.txt
pi@raspberrypi ~/main $ file my_file.txt
my_file.txt: ASCII text
pi@raspberrypi ~/main $ hexdump -C my_file.txt

00000000  73 61 6d 70 6c 65 20 61  6e 73 77 65 72 2e 2e 0a  |sample answer...|
00000010
```

[Sample file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00025813595613790492)

**Python code:**

```
import json,httplib
from random import randint
import codecs

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/XXXX', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "xxxx",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "xxxx"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())

pos = randint(0,len(result['results'])-1)
sentence = result['results'][pos]['sentence'].encode('iso-8859-15')
response = result['results'][pos]['response'].encode('iso-8859-15')

text_file = codecs.open("sentence.txt", "w","ISO-8859-15")
text_file.write("%s" % sentence)
text_file.close()

text_file = open("response.txt","w")
text_file.write("%s" % response)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you upload the file with no line terminators? I would like to have a look at it.

Comment: Is it removing the 'dot', or does any edit fix it?  It might be that editing the file adds the end of line marker, rather than the dot causing the problem.

Comment: So it's a single line in that text file? And *does* it have a line terminator? And are you sure you're only removing the dot? You can validate using `hexdump -C`. When typing in vim, lines always seem to end with  `0x0a`, even though you cannot move the cursor to the next empty line. So I guess vim is indeed adding it when you remove the dot, or make any edit.

Comment: many thanks! yes, you are all right, just opening and saving the file with vim is enough

Comment: thank you @Arjan I edited the post with the command results

Comment: @Nidhoegger I uploaded a file. Is on the edited question. Many thanks

Comment: Please show the python code how you get the line and how you write it. I suspect that the newline is stripped when looping over the input and all you need to do is append it when writing the output file.  Please make sure to specify if you are using python 2 or 3 since unicode handling has changed a lot between those two versions.

Comment: Thanks @Bram, there it is. Using python 2.7.3. Writing to a file in two different ways, with same result.

Comment: So that specific example even has *two* dots, right? `0x2e` is a dot, and that's in the example twice. But indeed, the `0x0a` is added by vim, even when you don't even remove anything, like you already saw now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard `/bin/echo` can be used to add that newline to the end of the file for you:

```
$ echo -n 'ssss'>test
$ file test
test: ASCII text, with no line terminators
$ hexdump -C test 
00000000  73 73 73 73                                       |ssss|
00000004
$ echo >> test
$ file test
test: ASCII text
$ hexdump -C test 
00000000  73 73 73 73 0a                                    |ssss.|
00000005
$
```

Another option would be to add it in your Python code:

```py
text_file = open("response.txt","w")
text_file.write("%s" % response)
text_file.write("\n")  # <-- newline added here
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Or: `text_file.write("%s\n" % response)` ;-)

Comment: @Arjan that's probably how I would do it because I like things to be ultra-concise, but I wanted the extra verbosity for illustrative purposes here. :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to append the newline in the write command:

```
text_file.write("%s\n" % sentence)
```

My sample program to demonstrate

```
import codecs
sentence = 'something'
text_file = codecs.open("sentence.txt", "w","ISO-8859-15")
text_file.write("%s" % sentence)
text_file.close()
text_file = codecs.open("sentence2.txt", "w","ISO-8859-15")
text_file.write("%s\n" % sentence)
text_file.close()
```

And the result:

```
$ file sentence.txt 
sentence.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators
$ file sentence2.txt 
sentence2.txt: ASCII text
```

The explanation is that the variable you are writing does not contain the newline and `write()` writes exactly hat you give it.

Comment: Thank you, it works! your answer could be the acepted one perfectly, but Scott was quicker.